# Integral curves of complex function components

Tags: complex-analysis

How to generally find integral curves $F(x,y,c) = 0$ from $u(x, y), v(x, y)$ when

$$ x'(t) = u (x, y),\; y'(t) = v (x, y) $$

where $u, v$ are real and imaginary parts functions of a complex variable $w = f (z)$   for an independent parameter $t$ ?

What are the differential relations between  $ F , f$ or $ F, w $ ?

How is it possible to work further up from Cauchy-Riemann relations?

EDIT1:

Among the simplest functions $w = z^2$ ...  the integral curves turn out to be all circles tangential to x-axis at origin :

$$ F(x,y,c) = x^2 + y^2 - y \,c =0 $$

where $c$ is an arbitrary constant

EDIT2:

Motive to ask the question is .. I considered it fundamental in complex analysis.